# Спец.символы HTML после парсинга XLS файла

Tags: php, mysql

После парсинга XLS файла, если в файле встречаются Армянские символы, то они переводятся в спец. символы HTML, вот такой функцией:

```
function uc2html($str) {
        $ret = '';
        for( $i=0; $i<strlen($str)/2; $i++ ) {
                $charcode = ord($str[$i*2])+256*ord($str[$i*2+1]);
                $ret .= '&#'.$charcode;
        }
        return $ret;
}
```

Все было бы хорошо, если бы эти данные из файла не шли в базу, а сразу в HTML.
И в базе вместо слов 44&#44&#1392&#1396&#1397&#1414&#1379&#1397 приходят такие символы, как быть?()

Comment: chto nujno pomenyat v kode chto bi ne preobrazavala esli ya udalyayu etot kod nechego ne rabotaet...

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых замените

```
$ret .= '&#'.$charcode;
```

на

```
$ret .= '&#'.$charcode.';';
```

Во-вторых, перед записью в базу делайте

```
function mytestcallback($m) {
  return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
  }
$text = preg_replace_callback("/(&#[0-9]+;)/", "mytestcallback", $text);
```

это превратит все хтм-спецсимволы в символы юникода.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/hyeworld/hyeworld.com/html/aro1/SAMPLE/xls2mysql/index.php on line 179

Comment: Прошу прощения, не глядя вставлял. Обновил ответ, проверил, работает.

Answer (score 0):

А что Вы хотите сделать потом с этими данными? Пусть в базе такие и будут. После вывода в штмл они будут как надо...

Ну а если хотите в базу записывать как есть, то не преобразуйте.

К тому же, какая у Вас кодировка в базе?

Comment: у меня есть поиск который работает из базы,кодировка в базе utf 8 collation utf 8 general ci,как преобразовать эти символы в нормальные буквы????